# How should I send parameters to ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I recently created my first content provider. I had some trouble to send a parameters (an item id for example) to the content provider.

Assuming I have the following URIMatcher

```
private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    matcher.addURI(DatabaseContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, DatabaseContract.PATH_ITEM + "/#", ITEM_WITH_ID);

    return matcher;
}
```

I can send the given id using this loader

```
//...
cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(activity,
    DatabaseContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(itemId+"").build(),
    null,
    DatabaseContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ID + "= ?",
    new String[]{itemId},
    null);
//...
```

Or I can use this other one

```
//...
cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(activity,
    DatabaseContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(itemId+"").build(),
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);
//...
```

and retrieve the id from the Uri in the content provider using

```
String itemId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
```

Which one of the above loader should I use ? Why ?

**Why I'm asking this question**

There is not a lot of diferences between an http url and a content provider uri. Currently most web framework/librairies (like angular or vertx) use a router to retrieve data from uri. 
Why android does not have one ? It can be easily done based on UriMatcher...

Comment: read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#ContentURIs)

Comment: I did. So I have to use my first loader. But I did not find the why. Why the second loader should not be used ?